# How to add items to a JSON Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I have the following **`post`** method:

```
app.post('/sound', function (req, res) {

    var myYeArray = req.body;

    let retData = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < myYeArray['filter'].length; i++) {
        if (i > 3)
            break;

        var myEl = myYeArray['filter'][i];

        myPersSaveRevEntity.myPersSaveRevEntity(myEl, function (result) {
            console.log('GUID >>> ' + i + ' : ' + myEl['_myEntityGUID'] + ' >>> ' + JSON.stringify(result));

            Object.keys(result).forEach(function (key) {
                var row = result[key];
                // add items to retData
            });

        });
    }

    res.send(retData);
});
```

It gets a **`request`** that has an array JSON object; a list of database rows.

```
{ filter:
   [ { _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 100,
     _myEntityGUID: 101,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 119,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_comment',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Sat Aug 11 05:40:39 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Sat Aug 11 05:40:39 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 1,
     _myEntityGUID: 102,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 119,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_kiwi',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Sat Aug 11 06:57:04 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Sat Aug 11 06:57:04 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 1,
     _myEntityGUID: 103,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 119,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_video',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Sat Aug 11 07:38:44 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Sat Aug 11 07:38:44 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 1,
     _myEntityGUID: 104,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 119,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_video',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Sat Aug 11 09:11:00 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Sat Aug 11 09:11:00 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 100,
     _myEntityGUID: 105,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 119,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_comment',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Sat Aug 11 09:27:22 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Sat Aug 11 09:27:22 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 1,
     _myEntityGUID: 106,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 119,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_memo',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Sat Aug 11 09:56:00 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Sat Aug 11 09:56:00 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 104,
     _myEntityGUID: 107,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 119,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_comment',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Sat Aug 11 10:01:28 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Sat Aug 11 10:01:28 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 1,
     _myEntityGUID: 108,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 119,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_profile_pics_album',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Sat Aug 11 14:48:44 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Sat Aug 11 14:48:44 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 1,
     _myEntityGUID: 109,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 119,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_memo',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Sat Aug 11 15:40:17 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Sat Aug 11 15:40:17 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 104,
     _myEntityGUID: 110,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 119,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_comment',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Sat Aug 11 16:06:55 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Sat Aug 11 16:06:55 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 2,
     _myEntityGUID: 111,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 119,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_video',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Sat Aug 11 22:19:29 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Sat Aug 11 22:19:29 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 1,
     _myEntityGUID: 112,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 119,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_appointment',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Sun Aug 12 06:56:21 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Sun Aug 12 06:56:21 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 1,
     _myEntityGUID: 113,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 119,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_announcement',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Sun Aug 12 06:57:15 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Sun Aug 12 06:57:15 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 1,
     _myEntityGUID: 114,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 119,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_calendar',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Sun Aug 12 06:57:47 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Sun Aug 12 06:57:47 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 1,
     _myEntityGUID: 115,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 119,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_pics_album',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Sun Aug 12 07:20:23 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Sun Aug 12 07:20:23 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 1,
     _myEntityGUID: 116,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 119,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_memo',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Mon Aug 13 12:22:03 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Mon Aug 13 12:22:03 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 1,
     _myEntityGUID: 117,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 119,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_memo',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Mon Aug 13 12:26:03 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Mon Aug 13 12:26:03 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 1,
     _myEntityGUID: 118,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 119,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_memo',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Mon Aug 13 12:29:45 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Mon Aug 13 12:29:45 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: -1,
     _myEntityGUID: 119,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_user_entity',
     _myEntityType: 'my_user_entity',
     _timeCreated: 'Thu Aug 16 08:56:02 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Thu Aug 16 08:56:02 2018\n',
myUserEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: -1,
     _myEntityGUID: 120,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_user_entity',
     _myEntityType: 'my_user_entity',
     _timeCreated: 'Thu Aug 16 11:44:24 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Thu Aug 16 11:44:24 2018\n',
myUserEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: -1,
     _myEntityGUID: 121,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_user_entity',
     _myEntityType: 'my_user_entity',
     _timeCreated: 'Thu Aug 16 11:45:18 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Thu Aug 16 11:45:18 2018\n',
myUserEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: -1,
     _myEntityGUID: 122,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_user_entity',
     _myEntityType: 'my_user_entity',
     _timeCreated: 'Thu Aug 16 15:40:05 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Thu Aug 16 15:40:05 2018\n',
myUserEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: -1,
     _myEntityGUID: 123,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_user_entity',
     _myEntityType: 'my_user_entity',
     _timeCreated: 'Fri Aug 17 02:20:25 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Fri Aug 17 02:20:25 2018\n',
myUserEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 119,
     _myEntityGUID: 124,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 119,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_entity_info',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Sat Aug 18 06:27:10 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Sat Aug 18 06:27:10 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 120,
     _myEntityGUID: 125,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 120,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_entity_social_info',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Sun Aug 19 02:53:43 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Sun Aug 19 02:53:43 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 120,
     _myEntityGUID: 126,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 120,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_entity_info',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Sun Aug 19 02:54:36 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Sun Aug 19 02:54:36 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 1,
     _myEntityGUID: 127,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 120,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_kiwi',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Sun Aug 19 06:10:02 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Sun Aug 19 06:10:02 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 120,
     _myEntityGUID: 128,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 120,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_timeline',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Sun Aug 19 06:10:02 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Sun Aug 19 06:10:02 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 1,
     _myEntityGUID: 129,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 120,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_kiwi',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Sun Aug 19 10:41:55 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Sun Aug 19 10:41:55 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 1,
     _myEntityGUID: 130,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 120,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_timeline',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Sun Aug 19 10:41:55 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Sun Aug 19 10:41:55 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 1,
     _myEntityGUID: 131,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 120,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_kiwi',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Sun Aug 19 10:43:16 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Sun Aug 19 10:43:16 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 1,
     _myEntityGUID: 132,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 120,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_pics_album',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Sun Aug 19 10:43:16 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Sun Aug 19 10:43:16 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 132,
     _myEntityGUID: 133,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 120,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_comment',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Sun Aug 19 10:44:42 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Sun Aug 19 10:44:42 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 1,
     _myEntityGUID: 134,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 120,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_kiwi',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Sun Aug 19 16:55:10 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Sun Aug 19 16:55:10 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] },
{ _id: 0,
     _myEntityAccessPermission: 0,
     _myEntityContainerGUID: 1,
     _myEntityGUID: 135,
     _myEntityOwnerGUID: 120,
     _myEntitySiteGUID: -1,
     _myEntitySubType: 'my_kiwi',
     _myEntityType: 'my_object',
     _timeCreated: 'Sun Aug 19 17:00:44 2018\n',
     _timeUpdated: 'Sun Aug 19 17:00:44 2018\n',
myObjectEntity: [Object] } ] }
```

I iterate through the JSON array and save ach of the constituent JSON objects in a remote DB successfully.

The place I am failing at is that I would like to create a JSON array, and add ach item after persistence and send the resulting array in a **`response`**.

The method `myPersSaveRevEntity.myPersSaveRevEntity(myEl, function (result)` returns the last persisted table row:

```
GUID >>> 4 : 104 >>> [{"REMOTE_ENTITY_GUID":854,"LOCAL_ENTITY_GUID":101,"ENTITY_OWNER_GUID":119,"ENTITY_CONTAINER_GUID":100,"ENTITY_SITE_GUID":-1,"ENTITY_ACCESS_PERMISSION":0,"ENTITY_TYPE":"my_object","ENTITY_SUB_TYPE":"my_comment","COLUMN_NAME_CREATED_DATE":"Sat Aug 11 05:40:39 2018\n","COLUMN_NAME_UPDATED_DATE":"Sat Aug 11 05:40:39 2018\n"}]
```

How can I accomplish this?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: So what exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: Since you have asynchronous code within for loop, you would need to use either promises or library like async to handle callbacks and once all records have been processed, you would need to return result. Also, why are you using `Object.keys()` to iterate through `result`? It is an array and Object.keys() is used with objects.